# Does a character with a permanent True Polymorph effect reverts to their normal form upon reaching 0 HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The wording on true polymorph seems to imply the change back upon reaching 0 HP:

> The target assumes the hit points of its new form, and when it reverts to its normal form, the creature returns to the number of hit points it had before it transformed. If it reverts as a result of Dropping to 0 Hit Points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form. As long as the excess damage doesn't reduce the creature's normal form to 0 hit points, it isn't knocked Unconscious.

This wording is almost the same as wild shape:

> if you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form. For example, if you take 10 damage in animal form and have only 1 hit point left, you revert and take 9 damage. As long as the excess damage doesn’t reduce your normal form to 0 hit points, you aren’t knocked unconscious.

Answer (score 5):

### No.

Permanent means permanent. *true polymorph* reads:

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies. If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation lasts until it is dispelled.

So.  It is clearly saying that the transformation can end by reaching 0HP or losing concentration before reaching the duration.

Reaching the full duration makes the spell last until dispelled.  Meaning that in every way you are now whatever you were polymorphed into. While not an official ruling from Crawford, [it is clear from this tweet that the above is how Mike Mearls reads the same line](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/520355269272817664):

> nope, needs some sort of magical intercession to end it.

Comment: On the WoTC web site, most recent PHB errata indicates "until dispelled" ... which was first reflected in the SRD.

Comment: Note that this uses the old wording before errata. The new wording says "lasts until dispelled" instead of permanent. I have updated the wording.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: The revised wording makes the first line a little confusing, since now the spell doesn't actually say "permanent".

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm having some trouble with this. I see the updates on the SRD, but not in the most recent [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf). As such, I'm unclear on whether the change has been made to the PHB or not. Could you maybe provide a link to the "WoTC web site" where it said what you mentioned?

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme [here it is](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=188)  *The 
transformation lasts for the duration, or until the 
target drops to 0 hit points or dies. If you 
concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the 
transformation lasts until it is dispelled* [PHB errata is unclear](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf#page=3), but 2d or 3d printing had the change. (IIRC) Yeah, it's a mess.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme The Roll20 updated PHB has the same text.  *The transformation lasts for the d⁠uration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points⁠ or dies. If you concentrate on this spell for the full Duration, the transformation lasts until it is dispelled*  I actually preferred the original "it is permanent!" text, as it was less ambiguous.  9th level spell, and all that.